# Module not showing in OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

I try to code in eclipse and when I run it can not show me any error

This is test_module.py file

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class MyClass(osv.osv):
'''
  classdocs
'''
  _name='my.class'
  _columns={
      'name':fields.char("Name",size=128,),
      'code':fields.char("Code",size=127,),
           }
MYClass()

def __init__(selfparams):
'''
  Constructor
'''
```

and this is xml file

```
<?xml version=“1.0″ encoding=“utf-8″?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record model=“ir.ui.view” id=“test_base_form”>
      <field name=“name”>test.base.form</field>
      <field name=“model”>test.base</field>
      <field name=“type”>form</field>
      <field name=“arch” type=“xml”>
        <form string=“Test Base”>
          <field name=“name”/>
          <field name=“code”/>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
    <record model=“ir.ui.view” id=“test_base_tree”>
      <field name=“name”>test.base.tree</field>
      <field name=“model”>test.base</field>
      <field name=“type”>tree</field>
      <field name=“arch” type=“xml”>
        <tree string=“Test Base”>
          <field name=“name”/>
          <field name=“code”/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>
    <record model=“ir.actions.act_window” id=“action_test_seq”>
      <field name=“name”>Test Base</field>
      <field name=“res_model”>test.base</field>
      <field name=“view_type”>form</field>
      <field name=“view_mode”>tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id=“menu_test_base_main” name=“Test Base”/>
    <menuitem id=“menu_test_base” parent=“menu_test_base_main”
              name=“Test Base” action=“action_test_seq”/>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

and when I go to `__init__.py` file and import like this

```
import test_module
```

it can not me show any error 
then when I want to show this module and I go to settings-update module list 
then in OpenERP it can not show me any module 
Where is the problem?
I've tried so many times but can not show module in OpenERP

Comment: Please format the code correctly. I tried, but seems very difficult for others.

Comment: I think you are conceptually wrong. the model name in `Python` file and `XML` file are totally different.

Comment: you miss at least \_\_openerp\_\_.py file wich define the module as OpenERP module

Comment: i also add this file but i dnt mention here i add in eclipse

Comment: did you save the module in the right place (under the oddons/ folder)?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: Are you running the same addons in which your module resides? As it happened to me twice i was running another path and by mistake my module was in another. :D

Answer (score 1):

My problem with your question is that I can not understand what exactly you are doing. The code you posted doesn't show enough your approach and is very badly formatted.  For example the following

```
model=“ir.ui.view”
```

is not valid xml attribute definition because of the wrong quotes used. Should be like that:

```
model="ir.ui.view"
```

This is why I'll just give the basic steps I followed starting from your code.

First, the model definition in the file **test_module.py**

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class MyClass(osv.osv):
    '''
      classdocs
    '''

    _name='my.class'
    _columns={
        'name': fields.char("Name", size=128,),
        'code': fields.char("Code", size=127,),
    }


# Corrected - MyClass() instead of MYClass()    
MyClass()
```

Nothing special here except that you had misspell the class name when instantiating it. I also removed the __init__() method because his place is not where you put it.

Second, the **__init__.py** file to load your new model:

```
import test_module
```

And now, the XML file containing the view, action and menu definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_form">
            <field name="name">test.base.form</field>
            <!-- corrected to have the right model as programmed in test_module.py -->
            <field name="model">my.class</field>
            <field name="type">form</field> 
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Test Base">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="code"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test_base_tree">
            <field name="name">test.base.tree</field>
            <!-- corrected to have the right model as programmed in test_module.py -->
            <field name="model">my.class</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Test Base">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="code"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_test_seq">
            <field name="name">Test Base</field>
            <!-- corrected to have the right model as programmed in test_module.py -->
            <field name="res_model">my.class</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="menu_test_base_main" name="Test Base"/>
        <!-- Removed parent. You need an existing parent menu if you want to specify one -->
        <!-- Also the action attribute has to point to the action you just defined -->
        <menuitem id="menu_test_base" 
            name="Test Base" action="action_test_seq"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Take a look at my comments inside the XML.

The final step is the OpenERP module definition in the **__openerp__.py** file:

```
{
    'name': 'Test module',
    'description': 'Module for demonstration of the new module creation process in OpenERP',
    'category': 'Test',
    'author': 'Andrei Boyanov <andrei at novatus dot bg>',
    'website': 'http://novatus.bg',
    'version': '0.01',
    'depends': [],
    'init_xml': [],
    'update_xml': [
        'test_view.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
}
```

One of the important things here is the list of XML files to take into account when updating.

After all of this I went in the *Administration -> Modules* menu and executed *Update Modules List*. When I filtered the modules by the name **test** your new module appeared in my list. I selected it for install and installed it trough the *Apply Scheduled Updates* menu action.

Et voilà - F5 for refresh and a new menu **TEST BASE** appeared in the main menu bar. Now I'm able do create new my.class objects in the database.

This receipt is valid for OpenERP 6.0. I didn't tested it on OpenERP 7 and I know that there are some differences in the module definition.